# How to create a simple reusable grid that only differs in store and title?

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs

Alright, I've spent some time with the ExtJs documentation but this still isn't clear to me. I'm basically just setting up an internal job monitor with a grid for each environment (dev, qa, uat, prod) in a respective tab in a panel. I'd like to make one reusable grid object that I create 4 times and just feed in the title and url to load the store with, but I can't understand from the documentation how to set this up. I know I have to extend from Grid, but it's not clear how to configure it from there. Right now I just have a quick and dirty implementation with some copy pasta, looking for the proper way to set this up:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    // setup the state provider, all state information will be saved to a cookie
    Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));

    Ext.define('Job',{
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: [
            'JOB_GROUP',
            'JOB_NAME',
            'START_TIME',
            'END_TIME',
            'RUNTIME',
            'STATUS',
            'OUTPUT'
        ]
    });

    var colModel = [
        {
            header: 'Job Group',
            dataIndex: 'JOB_GROUP'
        },
        {
            header: 'Job Name',
            dataIndex: 'JOB_NAME',
            width: 300
        },
        {
            header: 'Start Time',
            dataIndex: 'START_TIME',
            width: 120
        },
        {
            header: 'End Time',
            dataIndex: 'END_TIME',
            width: 120
        },
        {
            header: 'Runtime',
            dataIndex: 'RUNTIME',
            width: 100
        },
        {
            header: 'Status',
            dataIndex: 'STATUS',
            width: 100,
            renderer: statusColor
        }
    ];

    // create the data store
    var devStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: "Job",
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/jobview/servlet?env=DEV',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'DEV'
            }
        }
    });

    var qaStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: "Job",
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/jobview/servlet?env=QA',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'QA'
            }
        }
    });

    var uatStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: "Job",
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/jobview/servlet?env=UAT',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'UAT'
            }
        }
    });

    var prdStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: "Job",
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/jobview/servlet?env=PRD',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'PRD'
            }
        }
    });

    devStore.load();
    qaStore.load();
    uatStore.load();
    prdStore.load()

    var devGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: devStore,
        columns: colModel,
        width: 1000,
        autoHeight: true,
        title: 'DEV'
    });

     var qaGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: qaStore,
        columns: colModel,
        width: 1000,
        autoHeight: true,
        title: 'QA'
    });

    var uatGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: uatStore,
        columns: colModel,
        width: 1000,
        autoHeight: true,
        title: 'UAT'
    });

    var prdGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: prdStore,
        columns: colModel,
        //renderTo: 'example-grid',
        width: 1000,
        autoHeight: true,
        title: 'PRD'
    });

    var tabs = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
        renderTo: 'tabs',
        width: 1080,
        activeTab: 0,
        items: [
            devGrid,
            qaGrid,
            uatGrid,
            prdGrid
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In ExtJS 4:

```
Ext.define('BS.view.MyGrid' ,
{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.my-grid',

    // None complex configs (booleans, integers, strings) go here
    width: 1000,
    autoHeight: true

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            // complex configs (objects / arrays) go here
            columns: colModel,  
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, got it combined with help from the feedview example sencha provides.